# Prove the following identity: $\frac{1}{(\sec A + \tan A )}= \sec A - \tan A$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove the following identity: $\frac{1}{(\sec A + \tan A )}= \sec A - \tan A$

I searched for an answer on the net but found it really confusing. Can anyone help me with this with less number of steps?

Comment: $$(\sec A-\tan A)(\sec A+\tan A)=?$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee (sec A - tan A ) (sec A + tan A) = 1

Comment: So, if $ab=1, a=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\color{red}{\sec^2 A-\tan^2 A} = \frac{1-\sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A} = \color{red}{1}$$
hence by dividing both sides by $\sec A+\tan A$...